# Extract a numerical information from a Pandas column and insert it in a new column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column structured like this:  `album: "The Dark Side Of The Moon" (1973)`  there is the name of the album and at the end, between parenthesis, the year.

I just need to eliminate that last part from that column and create a new column called "year" with only the year.

I 'm not sure if use `re.search()` , but I've tried this:

```
data['year'] = data['Album'].str.extract(r'\(\d*\)')
```

this pattern works if I test it with re.search() on a single string and it works in online tools for regular expressions.

so what can I do?

thanks!

Comment: you need to wrap it in an extra set of parenthsis `((\d*\))` that should do the trick

Comment: No problemo, you should mark an answer as correct I'd recommend YOBEN_S :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should separate the years and the names of the albums and also strip them from the extra characters:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"album": ['"The Dark Side Of The Moon" (1973)']})

names = []
years = []
for i in range(len(data['album'])):
  year = data['album'][i].split()[-1]
  years.append(int(year.strip("()")))
  names.append(data['album'][i].replace(year,'').strip('" '))

data = pd.DataFrame(names,years)
```

Answer (score 1):

You still can use your re.search

```
data['year']=data['Album'].map(lambda x : re.search(r'\(\d*\)',x).group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using split:

```
data["year"] = data['Album'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("(")[1][0:-1]))
```